# How to get search value after search on React-Bootstrap-Table-Next

Tags: reactjs, datatable, react-bootstrap-table

I am trying to sync my URL query params with filter, sort, and search input so that users can revisit the list in the same state.

I see there's an [`afterSearch` prop on ToolkitProvider](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/search-props.html#searchaftersearch-function), but it doesn't receive the input value itself as a prop. I could cobble something together using DOM element methods and useEffect, but I'm curious if there is a more React kosher solution.

An additional issue to consider, is that if I access the DOM on `afterSearch` or something janky like this...

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.getElementById('search-bar-0').addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, false);

    return () => {
      document.getElementById('search-bar-0').removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown, false);
    };
  }, [thing]);

  function handleKeyDown(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value); // always one character behind
  }
```

...the value returned from `e.target.value` is always one character behind what is actually in the search input.

Comment: Use keyup instead. Why are you using the even listener instead of <input onKeyUp={..}?

Comment: Keyup works! Can't believe I didn't think of that. And you know what, I have a custom search component lying around that I can replace the OOTB one with and just use onKeyUp on. Thanks @lissettdm!

Answer (score 0):

A workaround for the search value not being returned as a param on something like `afterSearch`, is to create a [custom search component](https://react-bootstrap-table.github.io/react-bootstrap-table2/docs/basic-search.html#customize-search-component), and use `onKeyUp` on the input there.